# How to create SQLite Table without PrimaryKey and can it be used

Tags: sqlite, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create a sqlite table which serves as Common table only that used to set output targets.

For example:

1) user is allowed to enter the output target for a particular item

This class is not using the attributes:
 `[SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]`

```
class CommonOutputTargets
{   
    public int Output_Chair { get; set; }
    public int Output_CoffeeTable { get; set; }
    public int Output_BedFrame { get; set; }

   .....
}
```

I just want to retrive the item

example:

by output_chair and update a number into the table dynamically whenever a change is required.

Comment: How to Update the table? say, update Output_Chair = 3000.  Can not update as this table has no PrimaryKey

Comment: What is the problem with having a Primary Key?

Comment: I just need a row without PKey so that it will not create additional row.

Comment: It is not clearly with your question. Did you want to know how to create a Sqlite table without primary key?  Or did you want to know how to update table which doesn't have a primary key? What sqlite nuget package did you use maybe I can provide a demo for you.

Comment: want to know how to create a Sqlite table without primary key and how to update the fields .